# Data from R to Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, save, adjacency-matrix

I created an adjacency matrix with R and now I want to work on it in Matlab (CSV file contains `startnodes`, `endnodes` and `weights`).

```
a = read.csv(file.choose()) 

a[, 1] = as.character(a[,1]) 
a[, 2]=as.character(a[,2])
a = as.matrix(a) 
g = graph.edgelist(a[,1:2]) 
E(g)$weight = as.numeric(a[,3]) 

g2 = graph.data.frame(a)

adj = get.adjacency(g, attr='weight', sparse = TRUE)
```

Then, I get a Large `dgc` Matrix with 319 million elements. I cannot save this file using `R.matlab` package. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: What about an HDF5 file? I see there are R libraries for writing HDF5 and HDF5 is supported natively by MATLAB, and HDF5 can handle very large data sets.

Comment: I did install the package, but I cannot write the data to file ( h5write(adj) ) Do you have any ideas what´s wrong? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: h5write(adj, file = "adj.h5")

Comment: Am I understanding the problem correctly—`adj` here is a sparse array (319e6 elements but most of them zero, so uses a lot less memory) in R and you’d like to save this to a disk and load it into Matlab?

Comment: You can read csv directly in MATLAB and convert it to sparse matrix using function [sparse](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I was able to save the matrix as csv (640 mb) and it works fine on matlab! I am new to R and matlab so thanks a lot!!!